# Best Practice for Detecting Rails Version for Plugin Compatibility?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working on upgrading a plugin for Rails 3.0.5, specifically, [this commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/756e70cb4492ded56b72b1601da7d198eaf7b840).  Essentially, ActiveRecord requires a proc instead of a string for condition interpolation.

In general, I think the best way to handle something like this is with a `respond_to?` call, but in this case all of the methods that were changed are private.  What's the best practice for checking the rails version so that the plugin can give new versions a proc, and old versions a string?  I'd rather not rely on checking that private methods exist, since that is likely to break in the future.

Comment: from rails 2.3 you could use   "Rails.version"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Rails.version
# => "3.0.5"
Rails::VERSION::MAJOR
# => 3
Rails::VERSION::MINOR
# => 0
Rails::VERSION::TINY
# => 5
```

Comment: To compare gem versions, check out [`Gem::Version#<=>`](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/fca24a695d2ee3a0bdb9702b752b34d44def6a53/lib/rubygems/version.rb#L330)